# Problem appending text to file with system(), fgets and sprintf, in C

Tags: c, windows, command, system

The following code from the book "Head First C" apparently should work but (on Windows 10) I just get the content of `comment` printed out with ` preceding it, and no file is edited.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char* now()
{
    time_t t;
    time (&t);
    return asctime(localtime (&t));
}

int main()
{
    char comment[80];
    char cmd[120];
    fgets(comment, 80, stdin);
    sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> reports.log", comment, now());
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show the content of `cmd` before the `system`-call, e.g. by `fputs(cmd, stdout)`.

Comment: 1st step is to check the function return values of `localtime()`, `time()`,  `asctime()`, `fgets()`.  Were they as expected?`

Comment: 2nd: `cmd[120]` is not certainly big enough.  Try `snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> reports.log", comment, now());` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: This is, of course, a silly and potentially non-portable way to write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The book apparently seems written with Unix-like systems in mind. Windows `cmd` doesn't use single quotes, so the following code:

```
sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> reports.log", comment, now());
```

should be changed to use double quotes, like this:

```
sprintf(cmd, "echo \"%s %s\" >> reports.log", comment, now());
```

Comment: The return value of `system` may indicate the error.